# get session object in wordpress 4.2

Tags: wordpress, session

I need  in wordpress 4.2 to get session object to set flash message like

```
global $session;
$session->set_flashdata( 'item', 'value' );
```

But for this I have to set register_globals= 'on'
in php.ini and I dislike this way.

If there is way to get this $session object without setting register_globals= 'on' ?

I googled and find to write in first rows of config file:

```
if (!session_id()) {
    session_start();
}
```

but that did not help.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you talking about administrator area?

Comment: Do WordPress has global variable like `$session`?

Answer (score 0):

Use [**admin_notices**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_notices) hook, to display particular message on Admin section.

```
// Adds the action to the hook
add_action( 'admin_notices', 'your_custom_function' );

function your_custom_function() {
    ?>
    <div class="updated">
        <p><?php _e( 'Updated!', 'my-text-domain' ); ?></p>
    </div>
    <?php
}
```